# Trying to set PTR on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, ptr-record, named-conf

For the last 6 hours I've been trying to set a PTR for my server but I with no luck.

Checking with `host` give me:
`Host 44.244.208.173.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

My /etc/named.conf includes my zone:

```
zone "244.208.173.in-addr.arpa" {type master; file "/home/admin/conf/dns/rev.244.208.173.in-addr.arpa";};

rev.244.208.173.in-addr.arpa looks like this:

$TTL 14400
@    IN    SOA    domainscanada.ca.    root.domainscanada.ca. (
                                            2015041101
                                            7200
                                            3600
                                            1209600
                                            180 )

                                IN NS ns4.domainscanada.ca.
                                IN NS ns5.domainscanada.ca.
$ORIGIN 244.208.173.in-addr.arpa.
44      IN      PTR     volvo.mundyxm.com.
```

I'm without ideas of what to try next, maybe someone can have a look and spot the issue I am having ?

Comment: Do you own this netblock? In most cases, this has to be set by the provider hosting your server/IP and you can't just set up a reverse zone for this IP in your DNS server and expect this to work.

Comment: I have a dedicated server from wholesaleinternet.com and /29 netblock from them to use.

Comment: Did they delegate DNS for this netblock to you? Some providers will only offer some kind of web interface for you to edit the reverse entries. Check with their docs/support.

Comment: Thank you. I will check with my provider and will update this thread.

Comment: Thanks @Sven turns out that WholesaleInternet.com handle all rdns. I had to make a request to them.

Please post your answer and I will select it as the correct one. I'm sure others will have this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you can't do this as many (most) providers will not delegate reverse DNS to their customers and offer some other way to edit reverse entries (if at all).

When in doubt, check with your providers docs/support.